# WPF EventTriggers.EnterActions not working

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF EventTriggers.EnterActions not working.
Ust two similar Storyboard in Trigger.Actions - work, but in Trigger.EnterActions - no.

Trigger on checkbox 2 works, but trigger on checkbox 1 not firing.

WPF EventTriggers.EnterActions not working.
Ust two similar Storyboard in Trigger.Actions - work, but in Trigger.EnterActions - no.

```xml
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="checkbox 1">
            <CheckBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
                    <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="enter">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="1"
                                                    To="0.5"
                                                    Duration="0:0:1"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <EventTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="enter"/>
                    </EventTrigger.ExitActions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </CheckBox.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>

        <CheckBox Content="checkbox 2">
            <CheckBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation From="1"
                                                    To="0.5"
                                                    Duration="0:0:1"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </CheckBox.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: If you want to ask a different question, then create a new topic.
You should not replace the title and content of an existing topic.

Answer (score 0):

> WPF EventTriggers.EnterActions not working. Ust two similar Storyboard in Trigger.Actions - work, but in Trigger.EnterActions - no.

See [documentation TriggerBase.EnterActions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.triggerbase.enteractions?view=windowsdesktop-6.0):

> Gets a collection of TriggerAction objects to apply when the trigger object becomes active. This property does not apply to the EventTrigger class.